# Android remove Launcher

Tags: android, launcher

When I apply this code:

```
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : lst) {
            Log.d("TAG", "New Launcher Found: " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        }
```

I see 3 packages (which are launchers I guess). I want to remove one of them. How do I do it??

Comment: You should probably give more context what the actual issue is and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you should go to the settings, find the list of all apps, and remove it from there. If you want to do it programmatically, there is no way to remove other 3rd-party app.